# insert multi language text to database using entity framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4

for inserting value to the table using entity framework I have used this:

```
db.FileWavs.AddObject(wav);
db.SaveChanges();
```

To insert foreign language text I used N in query in front of values:

```
INSERT INTO FileWav (Description) values( N'थिच्नुहोस' )
```

But How can I used it in above code of entity framework.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do anything in entity framework, just make your field nvarchar() in database and you are done, then you can pass any UTF-8 without doing anything to entity framework.

Comment: I have Description - ntext and when inserting value it display all text as ???????

Comment: I use Persian with entity framework and there is no problem, the only thing I do different is I use it like db.FileWavs.Add(wav); , I don't know if it helps, but try it.